# Text won't write to page but will show in alert() message. JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am developing a form that will gather some information. I have something setup in my code where when the First Name text box changes (onchange), the sub header (`<td>`) will then get populated with the First Name.

For some reason, the text never gets written into the `<td>` which had the `id` of `subHeader` BUT when I do an alert message, it's there. What am I doing wrong?

JavaScript (Doesn't work):

```
function FirstName_onchange() {
    var LastName = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
    var FirstName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
    document.getElementById('subHeader').value = FirstName + " " + LastName;
}
```

JavaScript (Works):

```
function FirstName_onchange() {
    var LastName = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
    var FirstName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
    alert(document.getElementById('subHeader').value = FirstName + " " + LastName);
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td id="subHeader" colspan="4">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You should use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) instead of `value`

Comment: That did it. Why doesn't `.value` work for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<td>` tag has not value

just imagine this `<td value="sample"></td>`

you must use `.innerHTML` or `.innerTest` or `.textContent` instead

```
function FirstName_onchange() {
var LastName = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
var FirstName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
document.getElementById('subHeader').textContent = FirstName + " " + LastName;
}
```

Comment: @mwilson: You shouldn't use `innerHTML`. See FakeRainBrigand's answer for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The `.value` member is only for `<input />`, if you want to quickly set an element's content use `.textContent` (or `.innerText`) or `.innerHTML`, like so:

```
function FirstName_onchange() {

    var lastName  = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
    var firstName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
    document.getElementById('subHeader').textContent = firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

Note that `.textContent` is preferred over `.innerText`, and if you use `.innerHTML` then you should sanitize user input to prevent XSS attacks, for example.

Comment: @mwilson The textContent property is supported in all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Value is only a valid property for `<input />` and and `<textarea /`>.

You should use the `.innerHTML` or `.innerText` and `.textContent`.  Technically `innerText` isn't valid, but IE requires it.

```
function FirstName_onchange() {
    var LastName = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
    var FirstName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
    document.getElementById('subHeader').innerText = FirstName + " " + LastName;
    document.getElementById('subHeader').textContent = FirstName + " " + LastName;
}
```

Comment: If you use `innerHTML`, be sure to replace `<`, `>`, and `&` in the content with `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu, that's basically what `innerText`/`textContent` do, but yeah, that would be a security concern with innerHTML.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to point out that the OP should **not** just write `document.getElementById('subHeader').innerHTML = FirstName + " " + LastName;`, like the accepted answer does.

Answer (score 1):

By doing this

```
alert(document.getElementById('subHeader').value = FirstName + " " + LastName);
```

, you added a new property 'value' to the td object, and passed it to alert. That's why the alert worked.